# Microsoft Tape Format (MTF) Writing to a Tape - Windows

Tags: c++

I was successful with program for reading & writing the data of a tape but only concern is about MTF (Microsoft Tape Format), which I heard, that this is a standard format of writing the data to tape.

I've studied a document (link below) which explains the specifications of MTF but it's not very clear when I try to implement it programmatically. Can someone explain it clearly or give a sample program to achieve the same..?

http://laytongraphics.com/mtf/MTF_100a.PDF

I've got some programs/utilities which can read this format. But not writing..

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18098/Reading-MTF-Backup-Files perhaps?

Comment: Personally I would think **very carefully** before committing any data to a Microsoft Tape Format that hasn't been updated in 19 years!

Comment: `tar` on the other hand, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing) , has been around since 1979 and is well documented and supported...

Comment: @Mark Setchell But all the major companies write data to tape in MTF as per this document - [link] https://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=comparisons . Anyways, thanks for the suggestion. I will think over it again.. :)

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux - Any idea of a program to write in MTF instead of reading MTF ?? Both reading & writing seem similar, but there comes a difference while writing data in a particular offset.. Help me out if possible !!

Comment: No, I used only to read (old, damaged) tapes long time ago, sorry...

Comment: @Viswa _But all the major companies write data to tape in MTF as per this document_ - Please recognize the layout of that table: the products are in the columns, and only 1 (out of 9) product, "CA ARCserve" supports MTF. All others do not.

Comment: @tevemadar - Sorry that I didn't observe correctly. But I personally used and observed that Veeam B&R, Veritas Backup Exec, NetVault Backup implemented MTF in writing the data. As all these are major companies, I just got a doubt if we should use MTF in my utility as well.. !! Help me out in making a decision, if possible. Tks in advance.